# How to delete one row from table with one value where the table contains a second row with a different value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given the following table data:

```
+------+---------+----------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id   | version | quantity | state    | orderLineId | locationId | stockMoveTaskId | created             |
+------+---------+----------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 3277 |       0 |        2 | created  |      169108 |       5692 |            NULL | 2017-09-07 14:55:41 |
| 3073 |       0 |        2 | unpacked |      169108 |       5692 |            NULL | 2017-09-07 09:40:35 |
+------+---------+----------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Using MySQL - how can I delete all rows containing the state 'created' only when the table also contains a row with the state 'unpacked' given the order line id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use `delete` . . . with `join`:

```
delete todelete
    from t todelete join
         t
         on t.orderLineId = todelete.orderLineId
    where todelete.state = 'created' and t.state = 'unpacked';
```

Comment: @crm MySQL often has performance problems with `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)` so I always prefer joins.

Comment: I would agree that this version is the better option here. Simple is beautiful ... and performant!

Comment: @Barmar . . . More importantly, that construct will not work for `delete`, because the table being modified is in the subquery.  By definition, this is more performant, because this will work.

Comment: True. The performance issue comes up analogous `SELECT` statements.